# MySQL Order by count of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, count

I have a table `msg` like

```
msg_id|from|to|msg|
```

Now i want to select All `msg_id` whom i have most  msg with.

eg.
If i want to select my top 2 messengers in desc order(i am with id=2)

```
msg_id|from|to|msg|
1       2    3 Hi
2       2    3 Hi
3       2    4 Hi
4       3    2 Hi
5       3    4 Hi
6       4    2 Hi
7       3    2 Hi
8       1    2 Hi
9       2    4 Hi
10      3    2 Hi
```

The query will give me

`3` (since total msg =5 )

`4`  (since total msg =4 )

Comment: You can group by aggregate functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to use `UNION ALL` to combine your `to` and `from` columns (since either could contain the id you're looking for).  Then you can order by the `COUNT` descending:

```
select id
from (
  select `to` id, `from` contact
  from msg
  union all
  select `from`, `to`
  from msg
  ) t
where contact = 2
group by id
order by count(1) desc
limit 2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f0b7/6)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this..

SELECT count(to) AS num FROM msg GROUP BY to ORDER BY num LIMIT 2;

I am not 100% sure if this is exact format as I do not have anything to test with. However it should give you close to the correct answer (syntax errors aside).

Comment: and what if `to` is  `the other user` who sends msg